# Pygame - How do I create multiple sprite objects at once?

Tags: python

I want to be able to create multiple car sprite objects but within x += 10 of each other like a parking lot. How do I go about this? It keeps spawning on top of each other. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#class
 class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.image.load('car.png')
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #in my main game to create
        for i in range(3):
            car = Car()
            car.rect.x +=15
            car_sprite_list.add(car)
```

Answer (score 0):

`car.rect.x` probably starts off as being `0`, so since `0 + 15 = 15`, all of the cars will have the same `x` coordinate. Try using `i`:

```
car.rect.x = 15 * i
```